# Dojo dialog button calling external function

Tags: dialog, dojo

I have a dialog which is called the following way

```
var dlg = new dijit.Dialog({
        'title': 'my title',
        'content': '<iframe style=\'width: 100%;\' id=\'myId\' src=\'' + mySource \' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\'></iframe>',
        'id': 'myId',
        'style': 'width:420px; overflow:hidden',
        'parseOnLoad' : true,
        'autofocus': true
    });

    var actionBar = dojo.create('div', {
        'class': 'footerClass'},
        dlg.containerNode);

    var confirm = new dijit.form.Button({
        'label': 'ok',
        'baseClass': 'button'      
    }).placeAt(actionBar);

    var cancel = new dijit.form.Button({
        'label': 'Cancel',
        'baseClass': 'button'      
    }).placeAt(actionBar);
```

Is it possible to connect to the ok button and do onClick BUT call a function which is outside the connect ie:

```
dojo.connect(ok, 'onClick', null, dojo.hitch(ok, function() {

//Do some stuff....

//now call my other function which is outside this connect
myFunction()

})

function myFunction() {

//do some stuff

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What dojo version are you using ?

Comment: you can... ex.http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/wwj6w/